# How to do these types of MVC routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two routes registered:

```
//News page routing with optional news article ID
routes.MapRoute(
name: "News",
url: "news/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

with the default link (no id) generated as: `@Html.ActionLink("News", "Index", "News")`

and

```
//User page routing with User ID
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Profile",
url: "{id}/{controller}/{action}",
defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

with the link generated as:

```
[a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Account", new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = "test-user-id" }))"]Me[/a]
```

All good so far, my News link created as domain/news and works, and Me link created as domain/test-user-id and works too.

But once I visit the Me link, the News link becomes domain/news/test-user-id, which is not what i want. How do I "separate" News id and User id using mvc routing??

Answer (score 0):

In the News link your url has the controller first then the action.

You should follow the same pattern in the Me link. i.e.

{controller}/{action}/{id}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why that happens, but I have a couple of suggestions for the routing.  First, for the user route, remove the `UrlParameter.Optional`, since it is not actually optional.  Also, remove the `{controller}` and `{action}` from the URL template, since they are not necessary.

```
//User page routing with User ID
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Profile",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index" }
);
```

Second, use `@Url.RouteUrl` instead of `@Url.Action` for the profile link, as that more precisely targets the routing rule.

**News**:

```
@Html.RouteLink("News", "News")
```

**Profile**:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("Profile", new { id = "test-user-id" })
```